# I don't understand why this XPath expression is not working as a Scrapy selector

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I am just beginning to learn Scrapy, and I do not understand why the XPath described below is returning zero results.

I am trying to build a spider that crawls http://www.foodsafety.gov/recalls/recent/index.html

Specifically in my testing with the Scrapy shell I was trying to extract the headlines. Using the inspector in Safari's developer console I determined that the XPath for the headline text is //div[@id="recallList"]/h2/a/text(). Using find in the developer console I was able to locate 25 headlines with the above XPath.

However, when I use the Scrapy shell to test the XPath I get an empty list using

```
>> response.xpath('//div[@id="recallList"]/h2/a/text()').extract()
```

I am using

```
>> scrapy shell "http://www.foodsafety.gov/recalls/recent/index.html"
```

to crawl the site.

Comment: My guess is that the content is loaded asynchronously via JavaScript. Looking at the page source, I only see `<div id="recallList">&#160;</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response gives empty result because the content is loaded through Javascript which is not supported by scrapy as of now. If you'll look in the `network` panel in the developer console, you will see a another request is made to this url `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&callback=jsonp1455174771252&q=http://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/ContactFDA/StayInformed/RSSFeeds/FoodSafety/rss.xml&num=13` which returns a `json`. You can use this url to get all your data.

Comment: The direct feed URL could be even easier to parse: http://www.fda.gov/AboutFDA/ContactFDA/StayInformed/RSSFeeds/FoodSafety/rss.xml